# ASP .NET - Save copy of existing data before updating in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to ensure that the websites users don't mess up the primary data table so before each update the non-updated data should be stored into a history table.

I am thinking of using the 'RowUpdating' event on the GridView to do this.

How do I manually run a insert query using my existing SQLDataSource?

Overall flow would work like this:

1. gridview shows
   field1 field2
   test   1234
2. user edits gridview values
   field1 field2
   test    3333
   3a. user selects 'update' button
   3b.  system records that data was test,1234

Comment: Few years ago I did a project with a electric company, they request every update (add, delete as well) is recorded into a separate table. What we do this is to make all the database call to Stored Procedure, and we do the backup in the stored procedure.

Not sure if this answer your question, and this is just a share of experience. We did struggle  in deciding the implementation since the backup is too dependent to the code (We have no idea on Repository patterns, and the project is actually done with classic ASP VB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a trigger on the primary data table which chronicles the updates to the separate history table.  As long as this UI isn't going to be terribly busy and hitting the table like crazy, a trigger might be suitable.

Comment: Would the trigger pull the selected primary key value?

Comment: The trigger uses an ad hoc table (not sure if that's the proper term) which contains a record being inserted, updated or deleted.  For example in an INSERT operation on a given table, you would use "SELECT myPrimaryKey FROM Inserted", for a delete it would be "SELECT myPrimaryKey FROM Deleted".  You can set a variable to the key value, cursor with it, other operations.